# Oracle SQL Developer - Count function

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: output]

This is the output of a select * from table1, I have a doubt with count function... I want to count that NULL, in order to do that the proper option is to do this:

select count(*) from table1 where fecha_devolucion is null --> This gives me the proper answer counting 1 however if i do:

```
select count(fecha_devolucion)
  from table1
  where fecha_devolucion is null --> this returns 0, why? Isn't the same syntax?
```

What's the difference between choosing a specific field and * from a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm):

> If you specify expr, then COUNT returns the number of rows where expr
>   is not null. ...
>
> If you specify the asterisk (*), then this function returns all rows...

In other words, COUNT(fecha_devolucion) counts non-NULL values of that column.  COUNT(*) counts the total number of rows, regardless of the values.

Answer (score 1):

This is the another way how you can get the count :

```
SELECT SUM(NVL(fecha_devolucion,1)) FROM table1 WHERE fecha_devolucion IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare the two queries:

```
select count(*)
from table1
where fecha_devolucion is null;

select count(fecha_devolucion)
from table1
where fecha_devolucion is null;
```

I think you misunderstand the `count()` function.  This function counts the number of non-`NULL` values in its argument list.  With a constant or `*`, it counts all rows.

So, the first counts all the matching rows.  The second counts all the non-NULL values of `fecha_devolucion`.  But there are no such values because of the `where` clause.

By the way, you can also do:

```
select sum(case fecha_devolucion is null then 1 else 0 end) as Nullfecha_devolucion
from table1;
```